# Get variable from Matlab database

Tags: database, matlab, variables, import

If I have a database like this:

```
field = {'Name','GPA,'Salary'};
data = {'Jim', 3.2, $1000}
```

How to get data GPA '3.2' from my database to be my variable, so I can use it? Table name is 'data'.

Comment: in your example its `data{1,2}, but ifeel there is more to it than just those 2 lines of code. can you post the rest, maybe we can get a solution that always works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can work with this variables this is a matlab data structure called cell. the problem is that you have things that matlab can read

The first expression has an unclosed string

```
field = {'Name','GPA,'Salary'};
```

so it should be:

```
field = {'Name','GPA','Salary'};
```

The problem with the second is the dollar symbol you should or remove it or work as a string

```
data = {'Jim', 3.2, 1000}
```

then accessing to cell is easy [here is the documentation](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-cell-array.html)

```
field{2}

ans =

GPA
```

you can work with the numbers inside a cell, with positions you know that GPA is position 2:

```
>> data = {'Jim', 3.2, 1000}

data = 

    'Jim'    [3.2000]    [1000]

>> data{2} = data{2} + 0.8

data = 

    'Jim'    [4]    [1000]
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply sir , but if i want to equal GPA to another number ex : GPA + 0.8 , how to arithmatic it ?  what code i need use ?

Comment: thanks alot for the answer. I have another problem when i want to show database to gui, could you help me to solve it please? Code is below

Comment: it should be better to create a new question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39488338/reference-to-non-existent-field-error-when-showing-database-data-to-editbox-in-g